# A comic about a superman copycat who turns evil and starts terrorizing the world

Tags: story-identification, aliens, comics, super-hero

I'm looking for this comic book but can't remember the name. This is a slightly older and very long superhero comic that is completely independent from Marvel or DC.

It starts with an alien couple who changes their appearance to look human and visit Earth to help humanity. In the beginning they doesn't do anything and shares the cure for cancer with the locals in order to gain their trust.

After that, people accept them and they start doing heroic deeds under superhero names. One important is when the male one saved a young boy. Then calamity happen, a new particle accelerator goes haywire and creates a black hole while our heroes push it into space. It sucks in the female hero to who knows where and the male one stays alone.

Over the years he continues being a superhero and in his loneliness starts to date with a reporter. The young boy that he saved is grown up and become an expert about the hero. And he, along with the government, creates many fake accidents to test the hero's powers.

There is also a Lex Luthor-like figure who is like his ideological nemesis and funds extremist terrorist organizations and preaching that humanity cannot trust the **alien** hero.

Later, the hero fights someone, either the boy or the nemesis, who uses a device on the hero that turns him back into his alien form. He then says that humanity trusted the female superhero because she genuinely wanted to help them, but not in him. Behind his heroic deeds, people always felt that his eyes looked down on them and such.

While it's being broadcast to the whole world, the hero snaps and says that it was his beloved's idea and his beautiful mate even became this hideous thing (human) to help them and such. After his outburst and people seen his real self, the anti-alien mentality is in the rise. And after a while, the hero simply loses it and starts killing criminals, and then everyone else who is against him.

In the end, the boy creates a battle suit and fights with the fallen hero. The alien decides to leave Earth, but warns the boy to be ready for ***their*** arrival. And the last panel is the boy's garage full of battle suits, ready for whatever is to come.

It is not Irredeemable, Invincible or The Boys!

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: @LogicDictates I don't know, I read it before 2018 and I think it's maybe from the 00's.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BewareTheSuperman/ComicBooks

Comment: Mark Waid's *Irredeemable* has a similar idea, but if I remember correctly, the details are different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irredeemable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this ***[The Rise and Fall of Axiom](https://www.legendary.com/comics/axiom/)***, a 2016 graphic novel published by Legendary Comics...?

> [image: Front cover of "The Rise and Fall of Axiom" (2016).]

From a [review](https://www.pastemagazine.com/comics/mark-waid/axiom-is-the-worst-version):

> **The titular Axiom, seemingly an Aryan dream in spandex and a cape, arrives on Earth with his beautiful partner, Thena, and sets about curing cancer** (although it’s weirdly specified that they can’t fix heart disease or HIV) and shielding humanity from itself. **A Lex Luthor/Tony Stark hybrid fusses over Earth’s reliance on saviors from the sky, but provides little menace to the extraterrestrial heroes. When a physics experiment goes wrong and Thena sacrifices herself for the sake of the planet, Axiom quickly appoints himself Super-Dictator and attempts to rule the planet with an iron fist and heat vision before a secret coalition of government-sponsored human resistors convince him to rethink his choices and high-tail it off-planet.**

From another [review](https://worldcomicbookreview.com/2016/09/21/rise-fall-axiom-review/):

> **Axiom, driven by the loss of his companion, tries to find solace in a human female at first – a subtle allusion to Superman’s longstanding human romantic interest, Lois Lane** – but this soon fails.
>
> [...]
>
> **Axiom’s and Thena’s actual appearance, as to be expected of extraterrestrials, is inhuman and hideous to Earthlings. The two aliens felt compelled to adopt features pleasing to human eyes.** This also hints at one of the creature’s frustrations – Thena is apparently considered beautiful in their home world, but hid this in order not to aesthetically offend humans.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!